# _app pageProps from getInitialProps is empty object on all routes except home route "/"

Tags: next.js

I am trying to conditionally render a Next js component based on API data that I am fetching in `getInitialProps` in _app.js:

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: AppContext): Promise<AppInitialProps> => {
  const response = await fetchData();
  const _ctx = await App.getInitialProps(context);
 
  const ctx = {
    response,
    ..._ctx,
  };
  return { ...ctx };
};
```

The issue I am facing is, _app `pageProps` and thus my response data from `getInitialProps` is empty object on all routes except  home route "/". If I load my app directly to the landing page i.e. "/", the data comes through correctly.

If I navigate to a URL directly e.g. "/about" the data is not available.

How do I rectify this?

Comment: Have you tried this? [Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats)
`When you add getInitialProps in your custom app, you must import App from "next/app", call App.getInitialProps(appContext) inside getInitialProps and merge the returned object into the return value.`

Comment: Can you show us how you're accessing the `response` data in the home page and in the about page? Can you also show us the React component part of `MyApp`?

Comment: @PiyushSatija and @juliomalves , thank you for responding. Please see below the react component of MyApp and how I am accessing the data in the /about page.

`import App, { AppContext, AppInitialProps, AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, err }: AppProps & { err: unknown }) {
  const headerLogo = data?.find(({ name }) => name === 'my-logo');

  return (
    <>
  ...HEAD TAG AND META DATA
        <Layout Component={<Component {...pageProps} err={err} />} headerLogo={headerLogo}/>
    </>
  );
}

.....GET INITIAL PROPS 

export default MyApp;`

Answer (score 0):

Since the returned value from App.getInitialProps contains a pageProps property the object you're currently returning looks like:

```
{response: response, pageProps: {}}
```

You might want to put your response inside the pageProps as follows:

```
{pageProps: {response: response}}
```

Otherwise you could access the response in your MyApp like:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, response, err }: AppProps & { err: unknown }) {...}
```